# Which of these two textbook equations of geodesic deviation is correct?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics

My previous question [Textbook disagreement on geodesic deviation on a 2-sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132782/) got shot down as “off topic”, so I'm having a second stab at it.

Misner *et al*'s *Gravitation* (p34) gives the [geodesic deviation equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_deviation) as$$\frac{D^{2}\xi^{\alpha}}{D\tau^{2}}+R_{\phantom{\mu}\beta\gamma\delta}^{\alpha}\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d\tau}\xi^{\gamma}\frac{dx^{\delta}}{d\tau}=0,$$
 with the right-hand side $\xi$
  index $\gamma$
  equal to the *second* lower index on the Riemann tensor. Lambourne's *Relativity, Gravitation and Cosmology* (p185), on the other hand, gives $$\frac{D^{2}\xi^{\mu}}{D\lambda^{2}}+R_{\phantom{\mu}\alpha\beta\gamma}^{\mu}\xi^{\alpha}\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\gamma}}{d\lambda}=0,$$
 with the right-hand side $\xi$
  index $\alpha$
  equal to the *first* lower index on the Riemann tensor.

My question is, which of these two equations is correct?

I tried to answer this question myself by using the two equations to calculate the geodesic deviation on the surface of a unit 2-sphere. With Misner's equation (substituting $\lambda$ for $\tau$) I got $$\frac{D^{2}\xi^{\theta}}{D\lambda^{2}}=\left(\sin^{2}\theta\right)\left(u^{\phi}u^{\theta}\right)\xi^{\phi}-\left(\sin^{2}\theta\right)\left(u^{\phi}u^{\phi}\right)\xi^{\theta}$$
 and $$\frac{D^{2}\xi^{\phi}}{D\lambda^{2}}=\xi^{\theta}\left(u^{\theta}u^{\phi}\right)-\xi^{\phi}\left(u^{\theta}u^{\theta}\right).$$

You can see my calculation on my previous question [Textbook disagreement on geodesic deviation on a 2-sphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132782/) With Lambourne's equation I got

$$\frac{D^{2}\xi^{\theta}}{D\lambda^{2}}=0$$
 and $$\frac{D^{2}\xi^{\phi}}{D\lambda^{2}}=0.$$
  This didn't seem right to me so I concluded that Lambourne's equation is incorrect.

Comment: The proper method of dealing with a closed question is to *edit* the closed question, not write it out again (albeit slightly modified). If you merge this question with your other, closed one, I will be willing to nominate for reopening.

Comment: There are two different conventions for the Riemann tensor, and the tensors can differ by a minus sign between the two conventions.  Without telling us which version the two books are using, this question, as written, is unanswerable, since the two expressions you give also differ by a minus sign.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: Lambourne uses +--- and MTW use -+++

Comment: @JohnRennie: yes, but there is an additional convention on the Riemann tensor, depending on whether $\nabla_{[a}\nabla_{b]}\omega_{c} = R_{abc}{}^{d}\omega_{d}$ or whether $\nabla_{[a}\nabla_{b]}\omega_{c} = R^{d}{}_{abc}{}\omega_{d}$.  But looking at these two expressions again, the second one is wrong, as it is always identically zero.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: oops, yes, sorry I didn't read your comment carefully enough. I have both books but don't know them well enough to find the relevant sections without a prolonged search. I guess I'll admit defeat :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite my comment, on second look your second equation, attributed to Lambourne, is always identically zero.  This is because you multiply the symmetric tensor

$$\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\gamma}}{d\lambda}$$

against $R^{\mu}{}_{\nu\beta\gamma}$, and the riemann tensor is antisymmetric on those last two indices, and tracing a symmetric tensor against an antisymmetric tensor always gives zero.

Comment: Peter has faithfully reproduced the equation from Lambourne. I note gj255 now suggests this is a mistake in Lambourne's book.

Comment: I found it difficult to understand the stuff about oppositely signed Riemann tensors, but thanks for letting me know that Lambourne's equation is incorrect. Looking through various examples of the geodesic deviation equations online, they all seem to show the right-hand side $\xi$ index as equal to the *second* or *third* lower index on the Riemann tensor. I guess that corresponds to whether the Riemann tensor is positively or negatively signed.

Comment: @Peter4075: all that's going on with that is the fact that the Riemann tensor is defined by $\nabla_{a}\nabla_{b}\omega_{c} - \nabla_{b}\nabla_{a}\omega_{c}$.  It's an arbitrary choice whether you put the fourth index that you contract on $\omega$ first or last, so this could be either equal to $R_{abc}{}^{d}\omega_{d}$ or $R^{d}{}_{abc}\omega_{d}$.  Using the properties of the Riemann Tensor, you can juggle indices around, and show that these two definitions are equal to each other, except that they differ by a minus sign.

Comment: @jerryschirmer - sorry to come back to this, but I woke up in the middle of last night and realised I don't understand why$$\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\gamma}}{d\lambda}$$
 is a symmetric tensor. My understanding of a ST is at the level of a symmetric matrix. Why should the tensor product of $\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d\lambda}$
  and $\frac{dx^{\gamma}}{d\lambda}$
  give a symmetric matrix? Can't they each be a set of any four numbers? Thanks

Comment: No, they can't! Both expressions are exactly the _same_ 4-vector --- they are the spacetime co-ordinates of a particular point particle.

Comment: @Peter4075 it's just because $\frac{dx^\beta}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^\gamma}{d\lambda}=\frac{dx^\gamma}{d\lambda} \frac{dx^\beta}{d\lambda}$ :)

Comment: @Peter4075: they're two copies of the SAME set of four functions.

Comment: So if, for eg, we had $x,y,z$ coordinates, the two terms would multiply out to give a symmetric matrix

$$\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d\lambda}\frac{dx^{\gamma}}{d\lambda}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{dx}{d\lambda}\frac{dx}{d\lambda} & \frac{dx}{d\lambda}\frac{dy}{d\lambda} & \frac{dx}{d\lambda}\frac{dz}{d\lambda}\\
\frac{dy}{d\lambda}\frac{dx}{d\lambda} & \frac{dy}{d\lambda}\frac{dy}{d\lambda} & \frac{dy}{d\lambda}\frac{dz}{d\lambda}\\
\frac{dz}{d\lambda}\frac{dx}{d\lambda} & \frac{dz}{d\lambda}\frac{dy}{d\lambda} & \frac{dz}{d\lambda}\frac{dz}{d\lambda}
\end{array}\right)$$
 aka a symmetric tensor.

Comment: I know this is ultra longwinded, but I think I see it now.

Comment: @Peter4075: that's the best thing to do when something isn't clear.  Do it the long way, and then make sense of the short way argument about it.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT2: I've just seen Jerry Schirmer's answer, which confirms to me that Lambourne's equation is incorrect. I would mark his as the accepted answer. I'll leave the below for reference, though it is entirely false! Indeed, as pointed out by Peter in the comments, Lambourne uses the same convention as MTW for the Riemann tensor (see equation 3.35). Funnily, this doesn't appear in the August 2012 [errata](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/astronomy/cosmology-and-relativity/relativity-gravitation-and-cosmology) of the book --- perhaps somebody should email him.

In Misner, Thorne and Wheeler, the Riemann tensor is given by
$$ R^\mu{}_{\alpha \beta \gamma} = \frac{\partial \Gamma^\mu{}_{\alpha \gamma}}{\partial x^\beta} - \frac{\partial \Gamma^\mu{}_{\alpha \beta}}{\partial x^\gamma} + \Gamma^\mu{}_{\sigma \beta} \Gamma^\sigma{}_{\gamma \alpha} - \Gamma^\mu{}_{\sigma \gamma} \Gamma^\sigma{}_{\beta \alpha} $$
I believe Lambourne defines $R^\mu{}_{\alpha \beta \gamma}$ to be precisely the negative of this quantity. Now the Riemann tensor has various symmetries. The ones relevant here are

$$R_{abcd} = - R_{bacd} $$
$$R_{abcd} = - R_{abdc} $$
$$R_{abcd} = + R_{cdab} $$

With these symmetries and the two conventions considered, you see that the two equations of geodesic deviation are identical.

EDIT1: I've just noticed that this isn't right, despite the up-votes. If we think of the four indices on the Riemann tensor in pairs (1 and 2, and 3 and 4), the index on the separation vector sits with the free index in Lambourne, whereas it sits with one of the $\dot{x}$ terms in MTW. This is a significant difference, and in fact I think Lambourne's equation might indeed be incorrect. I just found a PDF of the book and it appears you've reproduced the relevant equation (6.23) faithfully here.

Comment: I'm struggling to take this in, but Lambourne gives $$R_{\phantom{l}ijk}^{l}=\frac{\partial\Gamma_{ik}^{l}}{\partial x^{j}}-\frac{\partial\Gamma_{ij}^{l}}{\partial x^{k}}+\Gamma_{ik}^{m}\Gamma_{mj}^{l}-\Gamma_{ij}^{m}\Gamma_{mk}^{l}.$$